# What is the number above my matlab result

Tags: matlab

1.0e+07 *

```
0.0000    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000
0.0000    0.0003    0.0268    6.5660
```

What does the 1.0e+07 * mean?

Comment: Note the `*` after `1.0e+07`. This implies that all the other numbers you provided are multiplied by `1.0e+07` (which is ten million as @Spike pointed out). It is essentially shorthand for the situations where numbers are either very large or very small. In your situation you appear to have large, ie `6.5660 * 1.0e+07` along with small, `0.0000 * 1.0e+07`, so you might benefit from typing `format long` and then viewing again your variable.

Comment: Thanks that makes sense! seems so obvious now. The format long is very helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1e07 = 1 x 10^7

To get a better visual you could try

```
   format short e
   format long e
```

Might give you more decimal places to make sense of.

Like Colin says, the multiplier 1e07, applies to the entire matrix/array.

Comment: Thanks! using format is a nice touch.